# Keycloak email verification: how to redirect the user after the verification

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

Email verification URL  sometimes redirect to client page and sometimes redirect to key cloak verification page . i don't how to control this . 
is there is a way to do like so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the redirect_uri parameters to control it:

[image]

Reference:

https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/8.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource